# How to show widget in frontend?

Tags: widgets

**I'm sorry about my english.

I'm newbie in wordpress. I try to create a small widget for embed video from youtube or others video hosting. Everything is going well in backend (Wordpress adminsitrator).

This is the print screen >> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay9rS.gif

When i publish the widget in my sidebar, the widget does not appear anything.
But work fine in my backend.

This is my widget code:

```
<?php

 /**
 * Today Video Widget Class
 *
 */

class Today_video extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Widget setup.
     */
    function Today_video    () {
        /* Widget settings. */
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'tm_widget_today_video', 'description' => __('Display today video on your site', 'today_video') );

        /* Widget control settings. */
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'today_video' );

        /* Create the widget. */
        $this->WP_Widget( 'today_video' , __( 'Today Video' , 'today_video' ), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    }

    /**
     * The frontend function
     */
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );

        /* Our variables from the widget settings. */
        if(isset($instance))
        {
            if( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
                $title =                apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance[ 'title' ] );
            }

            if( isset( $instance[ 'template' ] ) ) {
                $template =             htmlspecialchars_decode( $instance[ 'template' ] );
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Backend widget settings
     */
    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        /* Strip tags for title and name to remove HTML (important for text inputs). */
        $instance['title'] =            strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );

        // htmlspecialchars to save html markup in database, at frontend we use htmlspecialchars_decode
        $instance['template'] =         htmlspecialchars($new_instance['template']);

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Displays the widget settings controls on the widget panel.
     *
     * Backend widget options form
     */
    function form( $instance ) {
        $defaults = array( 
            'title' => __(  'Today Video', 'today_video'), 
                            'template' => __('<iframe width="200" height="150" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tv49TbW5rEg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>', 'today_video'),
                        );

        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'hybrid'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" style="width:96%;float:right;" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <textarea id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'template' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'template' ); ?>"  style="width:100%;height:100px;"><?php echo $instance['template']; ?></textarea>
        </p>

    <?php
    }
} //Add function to widgets_init that'll load today_video
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget( "Today_video" );' ) );
?>
```

Can someone help me, Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `widget` method does not echo anything. If you want content to show up the widget needs to echo content.

```
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    extract( $args );

    /* Our variables from the widget settings. */
    if(isset($instance))
    {
        if( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
            $title =                apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance[ 'title' ] );
            // try this
            echo $title;
        }

        if( isset( $instance[ 'template' ] ) ) {
            $template =             htmlspecialchars_decode( $instance[ 'template' ] );
            // try this
            echo $template;
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

That is probably not the format you want but it should display your content. Be aware that widgets support several parameters such as `$before_title` and `after_title`. While you don't have to use those, it is generally a good idea.

### Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API

Comment: Solved. Thank you so much s_ha_dum for your help :)